# retrieve forign key first value in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lumen

I have three tables Products, Category and Images. Category and Image tables have relationship with Product table. when I have use `$all_product = Product::with('category','image')->get();`product information category information and image information are display successfully want i want is **Question :** how to retrieve the image arrays first value?

```
"all_objects": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "samsung",
        "price": "2000",
        "category_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:24",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:24",
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name": "android",
            "created_at": "2020-02-17 13:26:42",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-17 13:26:42"
        },
        "image": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "image_name": "image_787.jpeg",
                "product_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:25",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:25"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image_name": "image_539.jpeg",
                "product_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:25",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:25"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "image_name": "image_606.jpeg",
                "product_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:25",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:25"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "image_name": "image_102.jpeg",
                "product_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:26",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-17 13:27:26"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: `$one_object->image[0]?` or you mean with eloquent get only one result for images?.

Comment: i want to display one object of image array in Eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` method returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` so you can use all available methods on [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections).

To get your first image:

```php
$all_product = Product::with('category','image')->get();

foreach ($all_product as $product) {
    $first_image = optional($product->image)->first();

    // do whatever you want with the $first_image
}
```

The `optional()` method is used in a case product had no images (i.e `$product->images` was null).

Comment: this only takes the first image other image arrays are getting null

Comment: @MohamedRaza you have a list of products with eager loaded list of images for each one, you can use `first()` method to get the first item of the images. check my updated answer to see the full code.

Comment: My Question is not to retrieve foreign key object, please read it again carefully Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$all_product = App\Product::with(['category','image' => function ($query) {
    $query->first();
}])->get();
```

see [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: i tried with it and this method doesn't work, when we do this it only display the product id 01's first image other product's images are null

Comment: $all_product = Product::with('category','image')->get();

Comment: @Mohammad please note that: "The `limit` and `take` query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads.". The `first` method uses `take` internally.

Comment: it display first products array's image's array's first value and second product arrays images are null

Comment: you want add new attribute with ex : image_first to your result ?
and your result with all other images data ? @MohamedRaza